# Consumindo API ReactJs

Tags: react

Sou novo em ReactJs, quando tento consumir uma API local eu não consigo, acredito que seja essa mensagem:

> localhost You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

Meu código:

```
 export default class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        api: []
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3010/teste')
          .then(res => {
            const api = res.data;
            this.setState({ api  });
          })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <ul>
            { this.state.api.map(apiaux => 
            <div> 
            <li>{apiaux.id}</li>
            </div>
            )}
          </ul>
        )
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se o endereço http://localhost:3010/test está funcionando normalmente no browser (se ele retorna dados ou não). Mas acredito que algo está faltando no seu ambiente React. Se o plugin de javascript está ativado no seu browser, w se você utilizou boilerplate (que é uma estrutura inicial), verifique se está configurado corretamente. Minha sugestão é que você utilize o gerador de app
Que é mais ou menos parecido com isso

npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start

Outra alternativa é utilizar Rekit Studio. Ele ja vem com as principais bibliotecas e até com um editor próprio. Quando eu comecei utilizei ele, e ainda utilizo. Ainda estou aprendendo, tem muitos conceitos interessantes, que vai te ajudar na programação javascript ES6 e código JSX (que usam aquelas marcações pseudo Html como  e outros.

Answer (score -3):

Boa tarde,

Confira este link da microsoft, basicamente você terá de habilitar o JS no seu pc

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-enable-javascript-in-windows-88d27b37-6484-7fc0-17df-872f65168279